# How to get the objects in the targetList of a rich:pickList?

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I filled my rightList of the PickList with Objects from a web service, but when i select some elements, i want to get these elements in myManagedBean, because i'll affect them to an Object.

JSF :

```
            <h:form>
                <rich:panel>
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="criteresSaisie"
                        rowClasses="critereLigne" columnClasses="titreColonne,">

                        <h:outputLabel for="libelleCoplement" value="           "
                            size="20" />
                        <rich:pickList d="libelleCoplement" sourceCaption="Compléments"
                            targetCaption="Compléments sélectionnés"
                            value="#{listeCmpltDispoModel.listeCmpltSelect}" size="15"
                            addText="&gt;" addAllText="&gt;&gt;" removeText="&lt;"
                            removeAllText="&lt;&lt;" listWidth="270px" listHeight="110px"
                            orderable="true">
                            <f:converter converterId="cmpltsTitresConcerter" />
                            <f:selectItems value="#{listeCmpltDispoModel.listeCmpltDispo}"
                                var="liste" itemLabel="#{liste.libelleComplement}"
                                itemValue="#{liste.cdComplement}"/>

                        </rich:pickList>
                    </h:panelGrid>

                    <h:panelGroup>
                        <div align="right">
                            <h:panelGrid columns="8">
                                <h:commandButton value="Valider"
                                    action="#{saisieCmpltsTitreCtrl.valider}" />
                            </h:panelGrid>
                        </div>
                    </h:panelGroup>

                </rich:panel>
            </h:form>
```

The bean :

```
@ManagedBean(name = "listeCmpltDispoModel")
@SessionScoped
public class ListeCmpltDispoModel implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Long cdComplement;
private String libelleComplement;
private int nbCompl;

private List<ComplementsDispoSortieDTO> listeCmpltDispo ;
private List<ComplementsDispoSortieDTO> listeCmpltSelect ;

public ListeCmpltDispoModel() {
}

public Long getCodeComplement() {
    return cdComplement;
}

public void setCodeComplement(Long cdComplement) {
    this.cdComplement = cdComplement;
}

public String getLibelleComplement1() {
    return libelleComplement;
}

public void setLibelleComplement1(String libelleCoplement) {
    this.libelleComplement = libelleCoplement;
}

public Long getCdComplement() {
    return cdComplement;
}

public void setCdComplement(Long cdComplement) {
    this.cdComplement = cdComplement;
}


public String getLibelleComplement() {
    return libelleComplement;
}

public void setLibelleComplement(String libelleComplement) {
    this.libelleComplement = libelleComplement;
}

public List<ComplementsDispoSortieDTO> getListeCmpltDispo() {
    return listeCmpltDispo;
}

public void setListeCmpltDispo(List<ComplementsDispoSortieDTO> listeCmpltDispo) {
    this.listeCmpltDispo = listeCmpltDispo;
}

public int getNbCompl() {
    return nbCompl;
}

public void setNbCompl(int nbCompl) {
    this.nbCompl = nbCompl;
}

public List<ComplementsDispoSortieDTO> getListeCmpltSelect() {
    return listeCmpltSelect;
}

public void setListeCmpltSelect(List<ComplementsDispoSortieDTO> listeCmpltSelect) {
    this.listeCmpltSelect = listeCmpltSelect;
}
}
```

Converter :

```
@FacesConverter(value="cmpltsTitresConcerter")
public class CmpltsTitresConcerter implements Converter {

@SuppressWarnings("null")
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        String value){
    ComplementsDispoSortieDTO cmpltSelect = null;
    cmpltSelect.setCdComplement(Long.parseLong(value));
    return cmpltSelect;
}

public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object obj) {
    return String.valueOf(((ComplementsDispoSortieDTO) obj).getCdComplement());
}
 }
```

Any help is greatly apprectiated!

Comment: You put a few elements in the right column and you want to select some from those few? Why don't you put there only the elements that you need?

Comment: I want to only just the elements in the right side into an Object, I get only the code id!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughtly you need 3 things :

- Custom converter for your object (Object to String, String to Object)
- Getter/Setter with the List of your Objects choices
- Getter/Setter with the List of your Objects selected

Everything is perfectly described here : [RichFaces Showcase - pickList](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=pickList)

**EDIT :**

Adding this should fix your problem :

```
<rich:pickList ...>
    <f:converter converterId="cmpltsTitresConcerter" />
</rich:pickList>
```

also the converter property in `<f:selectItems />` is not valid : [f:selectItems](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/selectItems.html)

**EDIT :**

You should modify your converter like that to remove converting exceptions :

```
@FacesConverter(value="cmpltsTitresConcerter")
public class CmpltsTitresConcerter implements Converter
{
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value)
    {
        ComplementsDispoSortieDTO cmpltSelect = null;

        if(value != null)
        {
            cmpltSelect = new ComplementsDispoSortieDTO();
            cmpltSelect.setCdComplement(Long.parseLong(value));
        }

        return cmpltSelect;
    }

    public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object obj)
    {
        String result = null;

        if(obj != null)
        {
            result = String.valueOf(((ComplementsDispoSortieDTO) obj).getCdComplement());
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: The converter you are using is only on the left items. You need the `<f:converter />` for the right values.

Comment: Everything looks fine to me, can't help much.

Comment: thank you, I have this worning "converter id is not registered.", it's normal ?

Comment: Could you have a typo error _cmpltsTitresConcerter_ > _cmpltsTitresConverter_

Comment: no, I have this one : "java.lang.Long cannot be cast to xx.xxx.declarationreglementaire.complementstitre.ComplementsDispoSortieDTO" and "xx.xxxxx.decrgltpresentation.backing.CmpltsTitresConcerter.getAsString(CmpltsTitresConcerter.java:23)"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30414/discussion-between-alexandre-lavoie-and-safwen-khalloufi)

Answer (score 0):

Your selected objects are bound to the value attribute which must have a getter and setter.

Comment: Yes I have getter and setter in my object, but I got a string value (memory case) or I should select one attribute, but I want to get the object